# Creating Vector elements without calling a constructor

Tags: c++, class, object, vector, element

Lets say I have two classes car and service. Is it possible to create the elements for both vector objects(note: I don't know if is actually refereed to as vector objects), of the car and service classes. Once both elements are created I would only like the car class constructor to be called later to have the service constructor called to get the user information?

Also if it is possible is it possible without having to change the Service constructor to a method?

```
   using namespace std; // I know this is not the best, prof wants us to use it

   class Car { Car() { //Get data from user } };

   class Service { Service(){ //Get data from user } };

   int main () {

       int num;
       vector<Car> car; 
       vector<Service> service;

       car.push_back(Car{});
       service.push_back();

       for (int i = 0; i < car.size(); i++) 
            car[i].display(i);
       cout << endl << car.size() + 1 << ". exit";
       cin >> num;
       service[num].Service::Service();

   }
```

Comment: Are you looking for a `std:vector<std::optional<Service>>`? See [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional).

Comment: Please describe the problem you're trying to solve better (the problem description, minimalized, not what you are trying to do in code)

Comment: Instead of getting input from the users in the construction of the object, write a function that asks for what you need and then pass that to the constructor of the object.  Then you can return that object and use that to assign it to the vector element you want to.

Comment: You should start reading a beginner book of c++. What is inheritance, what is OOP and what virtual methods can do for you. Calling a constructor "some times later" is definitely the wrong idea how c++ works. So you should start with the basics

Comment: You can't have an object until a constructor has run. Why don't you move the `//Get data from user` out of the default constructor and into functions `Car getCarFromInput()` and `Service getServiceFromInput()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using a `std::map` instead of `std::vector` which choice naturally follows from your task. By using it, you will be storing valid Service elements only.

```
   map<int,Service> service;

   car.push_back(Car{});

   for (int i = 0; i < car.size(); i++) 
        car[i].display(i);
   cout << endl << car.size() + 1 << ". exit";
   cin >> num;
   service[num]; //Service constructor will be called
```

Answer (score 1):

Since C++11, you have the list-initialization for vector and other containers.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization

Which means, you can put an enumeration of elements in a vector while initialization.

You can use your own class constructor in it:

```
std::vector<Car> cars {Car(...), Car(...), Car(...)}; //C++11
```

Since I can't comment your question yet, is it what you expected?

Comment: I would like to create objects for both of my classes, both of which have a constructor. I would like both objects  to have a elements added  regardless,  although I would only like the car class constructor to be called and the service class constructor not to be.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking you are looking for something like this:

```
class Car {
private:
    std::string _make;
    std::string _model;
    std::string _vinNumber;

    std::size_t _year;

public:
    Car() : _year( 0 ) {} // default
    Car( const std::string& make, const std::string& model, 
         const std::string& vinNumber, const std::size_t& year ) :
      _make( make ), _model( model ), 
      _vinNumber( vinNumber ), _year( year ) {
    }

    void setCarInfo( const std::string& make, const std::string& model,
                     const std::string& vinNumber, const std::size_t& year ) {
        _make      = make;
        _model     = model;
        _vinNumber = vinNumber;
        _year      = year;
    }

    std::string makeOf() const { return _make; }
    std::string modelOf() const { return _model; }
    std::string vinNumberOf() const { return _vinNumber; }
    std::size_t yearOf() const { return _year; }

};

class Service {
private:
    std::string _dealership;
    std::size_t _currentMiles;

public:
    Serivce() {}

    std::string dealershipOf() const { return _dealership; }
    std:size_t  currentMilesOf() const { return _currentMiles; }

    void setOrChangeDealership( const std::string& dealership ) {
        _dealership = dealership;
    }

    void setOrChangeCurrentMiles( std::size_t miles ) {
        _currentMiles = miles;
    }

    void setOrChangeCurrentMiles( const std::size_t& miles ) {
        _currentMiles = miles;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Car> cars;
    std::vector<Service> services;

    // you can add Car to vector by either default constructor 
    // to be filled out later or by user defined constructor
    cars.push_back( Car( "Honda", "Civic", "75273250323XMD252AG9", 2017 ) );
    // or
    cars.push_back( Car() );
    // then you can at some point in time update elements in container
    cars[i].setCarInfo( "Dodge", "Charger", "9259356M325D2680A217B", 2015 );

    // As with the service class there is only a "default" constructor
    services.push_back( Service() );
    // Service's members will have to be updated manually and later.

    return 0;
}
```

Regardless of what container you use, or even if you have a single instance of a class object; a `CTOR` for that class will be called. The only way that one will not is if either A: you declare it as `protected` or `private` in the class the prevents the class from being declared which is used with inheritance and polymorphism, or if you declare the constructor as a deleted function: `SomeClass() = delete`. There is no possible way to have a class instance without its constructor being called either implicitly by the compiler or explicitly by you.

Even something as simple as this:

```
class A {
public:
    int x;
};

int main() {

   A a;
   a.x = 5;

   return 0;
}
```

The line `A a;` behind the scenes the compiler will invoke `A()` on `a` so it would actually look like this:

```
 A a();
```

Using its default constructor.